# How do I convert .DAT and .XML dumps into a readable database?

Tags: mysql, database, sql, xml

I have a program that keeps all data in a Derby database. The application itself has crashed but the company that supports the software has a utility that can sort of recover the database. I was sent a zip files containing one schema XML file and dozens of .DAT files which are the individual tables. Is there anyway to upload these into a working MySQL database or to convert the .DAT files into a readable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dat files have their own format - so you need to have a program that will read the files and export it into a text format(any type - csv, xml, tab separated etc).

it looks like you need to have as well the mysql schema done before importing the data so that calls for a program from your vendor or you can do it in house.